# Max Date Based on Different Input Parameters

Tags: sql

Can anyone let me know what I'm missing here?

```
SELECT    fld1,   fld2,    fld3, 
MAX(DATE)    OVER     (PARTITION    BY    fld1,    fld2,    fld3)
FROM table1 where fld1 = userinput1 and Fld2 = userinput2 and Fld3 = userinput3
```

When the user enters userinput1, userinput2 and userinput3, I want the max date based on that combination.
When the user enters only userinput1 and userinput3, I want the max date based on that combination: userinput1, userinput2.
When the user enters only userinput3, I want the max date based on that unerinput3.

In fact it can be any combination

```
Table1  has

Fld1    fld2   fld3   date

1         a     A      01/01/2014
1         a     A      01/02/2014
1         a     B      01/03/2014
1         b     C      01/04/2014
1         b     C      01/05/2014
1         c     D      01/06/2014
2         a     A      01/07/2014


userinput1  = 1
unerinput2  = a
userinput3  = A

Max Date should be  01/02/2014


userinput1  = 1
unerinput2  = a
userinput3  = user doesn’t enter anything

Max Date should be 01/03/2014


userinput1  = 1
unerinput2  = user doesn’t enter anything
userinput3  = user doesn’t enter anything

Max Date should be 01/06/2014



userinput1  = user doesn’t enter anything
unerinput2  = user doesn’t enter anything
userinput3  = user doesn’t enter anything


Max Date should be  01/07/2014
```

Thanks in advance
Ram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify what database you're using (which you should always do), so I'm assuming MS SQL Server.

If you only want the max(date) and aren't interested in other columns I think this code should work (unless I completely misunderstood what you want):

```
DECLARE @userinput1 int = 1
DECLARE @userinput2 char = 'a' 
DECLARE @userinput3 char = 'A'

SELECT MAX(DATE)
FROM Table1 
WHERE 
    fld1 = CASE WHEN @userinput1 IS NULL THEN fld1 ELSE @userinput1 END
    AND
    fld2 = CASE WHEN @userinput2 IS NULL THEN fld2 ELSE @userinput2 END
    AND
    fld3 = CASE WHEN @userinput3 IS NULL THEN fld3 ELSE @userinput3 END
```

Here's a [sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f8ad33/1) showing the output with different combinations of variables.